# How can I allow users to send private messages without revealing sender's address?

Tags: privatemsg

I have a community application which allows users to send private messages and it is built using 'Private Message' module. When a message is sent, the recipient sees the sender's original email address which he has used to register with the system. I would like to use a system generated email address without revealing sender's original email address.

Comment: Isn't it a feature request to Provate Message module? If so, it should be posted in their issue queue, not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 7.x-1.x branch of [Private Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) has this setting in the PM Email Notify submodule. When enabled, there is a *E-mail notify* tab on the settings page (**/admin/config/messaging/privatemsg**) that allows you to configure the email's from header.

[image]

By default, if this is blank, it will use the site's default system email. It sounds like the module is configured with another token that's referencing the sender's init email.

Comment: No problem. If this solved the problem, mark it  as the right answer for others who might have the same problem.